# Unable to disable Thumbs.db on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

I have enabled the Group Policy setting "Turn off caching of thumbnails in hidden thumbs.db files", but the Thumbs.db is still getting generated. 
I have also enabling the Group Policy setting "Turn off caching of thumbnail pictures", but that has not helped to resolve the issue either.

I verified in the registry that the value data for the following key-value is '1'

> Key: HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer   Value:
>   DisableThumbsDBOnNetworkFolders

***I would like to know 

1) how to disable the creation of Thumbs.db when the aforementioned setup is not working? 

 2) why the server is not respecting this configuration?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is that the clients are creating the thumbs.db files, not the server. Make sure your GPO is applied to all client OUs.